# Converting 32 bit MLP to 32 bit FLAC?

Tags: ubuntu, ffmpeg, flac

I have some .[MLP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meridian_Lossless_Packing) files which I'd like to convert to .FLAC for easier playback.

Examining the file with `ffmpeg version 0.8.13-4:0.8.13-0ubuntu0.12.04.1` I get

```
Stream #0.0: Audio: mlp, 96000 Hz, 5.1, s32
```

If I try to convert it with ffmpeg, I get this notification

```
Incompatible sample format 's32' for codec 'flac', auto-selecting format 's16'
Output #0, flac, to 'test1.flac':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf53.21.1
    Stream #0.0: Audio: flac, 96000 Hz, 5.1, s16, 200 kb/s
```

If I use a `libflac` encoder

```
$ flac test.mlp --endian=big --channels=6 --sample-rate=96000 --sign=signed --bps=32
ERROR: invalid bits per sample '32' (must be 8/16/24)
```

So there I'm limited to 24 bits.
Is there any way to get 32bit files from ffmpeg?

Comment: Try a `libflac` encoder. You can always store the uncompressed file somewhere, surely it’s not multiple terabytes, is it?

Comment: I get `ERROR: invalid bits per sample '32' (must be 8/16/24)` will add it to the question.

Comment: Haha, oh well. Next time, I’ll read the [fine print](https://xiph.org/flac/format.html#metadata_block_streaminfo) first: “Currently the reference encoder and decoders only support up to 24 bits per sample.”. Guess you’re out of luck, then.

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of `avconv` has support for 32 bit samples.

Comment: So does `ffmpeg`.